# Matlab gui 2006 compatibility with new version 2012

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run matlab gui code written in matlab via 2006. I believe the code worked with 2010, but while running 2012a, I just get blank outline of the gui without any of the buttons displayed. Any ideas? If you have any questions, I can provide more information.

Comment: I get an error when I open the GUIDE

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is

Comment: BTW Matlab has changed _a_ _lot_ in the last 6 years. A large number of functions have been deprecated and/or removed.  Its not uncommon for old matlab code to not work under newer versions of matlab

Comment: I had to change the display--select all and move it down on in the GUIDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected all and moved it down in GUIDE to see the buttons.